# Navegation view - Error cannot be cast to

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragment, cast

Estoy intentado hacer una **Navegation view** en android studio/java para mi aprendizaje personal y me he topado con el problema de que no puede iniciar la actividad [Obviamente están creados los fragments y el menú con dichos items] , me salta este error:

```
/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.artibe, PID: 12350
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.artibe/com.example.artibe.inicio}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.artibe.inicio cannot be cast to com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.artibe.inicio cannot be cast to com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
    at com.example.artibe.inicio.onCreate(inicio.java:25)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
```

Que se resume en que en la linea 25, donde hago el **Listener** me dice que no puede castearlo ¿ cual es el error que esta causando que crashee la aplicacion?

***Linea que falla:***

```
 navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener((BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener) mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
```

***Codigo completo:***

```
public class inicio extends AppCompatActivity {

    fragment_buscar fragmentBuscar = new fragment_buscar();
    fragment_menu fragmentMenu = new fragment_menu();
    fragment_tienda fragmentTienda = new fragment_tienda();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicio);

        BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.menu_navegacion);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener((BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener) mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    }

    private final BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNavigationItemReselected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.fragment_buscar:
                    loadFragment(fragmentBuscar);
                case R.id.fragment_menu:
                    loadFragment(fragmentMenu);
                case R.id.fragment_tienda:
                    loadFragment(fragmentTienda);
            }
        }
    };

    public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_general, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: implementaste la interface OnNavigationItem**Reselected**Listener en vez de OnNavigationItem**Selected**Listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La linea que indica del error:

```
navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener((BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener) mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
```

indica que deberías usar `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener` ya que así lo estas definiendo:

```
navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener((BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener) mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
```

Cambia lalínea anterior por :

```
 navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
           
              switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.fragment_buscar:
                    loadFragment(fragmentBuscar);
                    return true;
                case R.id.fragment_menu:
                    loadFragment(fragmentMenu);
                    return true;
                case R.id.fragment_tienda:
                    loadFragment(fragmentTienda);
                    return true;
            }
                return false;
        }
    });
```

además de esta forma no tendrás necesidad de usar:  `BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener`

Comment: Funciona perfecto! muchas gracias